# Objects properties not reachable from all classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, init, alloc, core-bluetooth

I have 3 classes in my project : HeliController, FlightView and ConnectionView.
HeliController stores some connection data which is to be used by both FlightView and ConnectionView.

In both ConnectionView and HeliController I have

```
// Interface
#import "HeliController.h"
@property (retain) HeliController *heliController;

// Implementation
@synthesize HeliController = _HeliController
```

The ConnectionView takes care of all connection methods, so this class receives the peripheral I am communication with. From here, I send the peripheral data to be stored in the HeliController (which also is the delegate for the peripheral class):

```
// ConnectionView.m
self.heliController = [[HeliController alloc] initWithDelegateAndPeripheral:self peripheral:peripheral]; 
// Self will receive callbacks from HeliController and the connected peripheral is stored in the HeliController

// HeliController.m:
- (id)initWithDelegateAndPeripheral:(id<HeliControllerDelegate>)delegate peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral{

if([super init]){
    self.peripheral = peripheral;
    self.peripheral.delegate = self;
}
return self;
```

}

Now I can reach the peripheral from ConnectionView with

```
self.heliController.peripheral
```

and see that both have addresses on stack:

```
_heliController HeliController *    0x0017f9e0
_peripheral CBPeripheral *  0x0017e570
```

From FlightView I also want to reach the peripheral data. I do

```
self.heliController = [[HeliController alloc] init];
```

and see in the debugger that self.heliController gets an address on stack

```
_heliController HeliController *    0x0018ac60
```

but the peripheral is nil

```
_peripheral CBPeripheral *  0x00000000
```

why is this? What am I forgetting? This problem occured when I had to restructure my application, and I can't figure out what I have done wrong.

Comment: for me it seems you are using different `init` sequences. in the **ConnectionView.h** the init sequence is `self.heliController = [[HeliController alloc] initWithDelegateAndPeripheral:self peripheral:peripheral];` and in the **FlightView.m** the init sequence is `self.heliController = [[HeliController alloc] init];` it looks you don't pass the same parameters in the case of the **FlightView.m** as you did in the case of the **ConnectionView.m**. am I right?

Comment: Thats right, but I thought that I got the same parameters when the first init was done before the second, thereby making the stored parameters available for FlightView. I am a beginner at objective-c so it is more my understanding that failes me

Comment: you create **two different** instances with **two different** contents. you **cannot** expect the same content from different classes which initialised different ways. this the main point of the OOP, you are creating different instances of an object with different contents. there is no relationship between the two individual instances. just check the pointers of the two different `heliController` class, they are definitely independent from each other.

Comment: Oh, okay. Is there a good way to share an object between different classes then? I mean, where all classes can edit the object at the same time? Sounds dangerous, but I think that will solve my problem.

Comment: you **can use only one instance** of any object, only one thing you need: **the pointer of the instance**. and you can reach the instance and its all contents via this pointer. if you have no change to pass this pointer thought the classes, you should implement the simpleton class model for the global classes, you should write the **singleton version of your class** in that case only one instance will be created of the current class (and never more than one) and you can use anywhere in your code that individual instance.

Comment: I will look in to singleton then. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My sollution was to send the heliController object to the FlightView when I changed between the views like this:

```
- (IBAction)changeViewToFlight:(id)sender {

FlightView *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FlightViewIdentifier"];

// Make sure the heliController object is passed on to the FlightView
vc.heliController = self.heliController;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```